# What is wrong with this abstract java class

Tags: java, abstract

Why should I make 'public class AbstractDemo' to 'class AbstractDemo'?

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract int b();
    public void d() {
        System.out.println("public void d()");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public int b() {
        return 1;
    }
}
    public class AbstractDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
//            A obj = new A();
            B obj = new B();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Who is asking you to? Did you get an error? Educated guess: Java compiler allows only one public class per file and its name has to match the file name. So make it non-public or change the file name.

Comment: But note that you will have to make the class with the main method public in order to run it.

Comment: 'AbstractAnything' is probably the wrong choice, since it's not abstract in the Java sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the problem of the abstract class.

You need to clear the concept of access modifier in java.

- In a java file only one class can be public at a time inside a java file and its name must be the name of the java file. Otherwise, if want to write `public` AbstractDemo class inside a java file with a different name, it gives the following error then:

```
The public type AbstractDemo must be defined in its own file
```